# Are there "old" neuron types in the neocortex?

Tags: genetics, brain, human-evolution, neuroanatomy

"Old" may mean a neuron type that appeared early in the tree of life, and it may mean – going together – that it comes early in the lineage tree of neuronal cells, rooted in the fertilized ovum:

[image]<sup>[[This](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6391/eaaq1723) is only for *Schmidtea mediterranea*. Could someone give me a link to a comparingly nice lineage tree for human neurons, please?]</sup>

My question is twofold:

1. Are there neuron types in the adult healthy brain co-present with some of their differentiated descendants?
2. Are there "old" neuron types in the neocortex, that either appeared early in the tree of life or come early in the lineage tree?